# Obtener last insert ID C#

Tags: mysql, c#, sql, c, poo

quiero obtener la ultima ID registrada en una tabla de MYSQL, estoy trabajando en C#, mi código es el siguiente :

```
 var connection = GetConnection();
        var command = new MySqlCommand();

        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = "insert into actividad (ID,Inicio,Fin,Nombre,ProductorEncargado)values(null,'" + Inicio + "','" + Fin + "','" + NombreActividad + "','" + Productor + "')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Connection.Close();
        long id = command.LastInsertedId;
```

Si bien, el long ID, me devuelve correctamente el numero de ID, quisiera saber como volver global esa variable, para utilizarla en otros métodos

Comment: Ese LONG decláralo `static`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! vos queres quedarte con el id.. el otro comentario te da una idea, pero de igual forma, podes guardarlo en una clase, en la misma clase o donde quieras. Tu pregunta, en realidad, es otra.. cual es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo declaras fuera de la función y le asignas el valor.

Ejemplo:

```
static long Id
private static void Consulta(){
var connection = GetConnection();
    var command = new MySqlCommand();

    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "insert into actividad (ID,Inicio,Fin,Nombre,ProductorEncargado)values(null,'" + Inicio + "','" + Fin + "','" + NombreActividad + "','" + Productor + "')";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Connection.Close();
     id = command.LastInsertedId; 
}
private static void Funcion()
{
  Console.WriteLine(id);//para demostrar que funciona
 }
```

Si las funciones son estáticas necesitarás que añadir static delante de la declaración para poder usarlo en otras funciones si no no hace falta.